# How do I Join 3 tables in Dbase?

Tags: dbase

I don't know anything about dBase, but I am trying to pull data out of a customer's old Dbase database. It's a set of .DBF files. I am using ODBC and DBeaver to pull out data, but when I Join more than 2 tables I get an error.

```
Select * 
from tableA 
Left Join tableB on tableA.Key = tableB.Key 
Left Join tableC on tableA.LINK = tableC.LINK
```

The error is:

> SQL Error [37000]: [Microsoft][ODBC dBASE Driver] Syntax error
> (missing operator) in query expression 'tableA.key = tableB.key LEFT
> JOIN tableC ON tableA.LINK = tableC.LIN'.

Comment: You can try rather inner join and the old sql syntax Select .. from tableA, tableB where ...

Comment: well, dang, Kalina. I think that did it. Thanks!